# Why -O2 has more number of instructions than compilation without optimization

Tags: c++, c++11, arm, atomic, compiler-explorer

I tried out following codes in https://godbolt.org/z/9xWvzcdbq without optimization option and https://godbolt.org/z/9WTocce97 with optimization option -O2

The without optimization option version generating 43 lines of assembly instructions with instruction `bl      std::atomic<int*>::load(std::memory_order) const` while the version with -O2 optimization option generating 49 lines of assembly instructions with data memory barrier `dmb     ish`.

Is that expected and why? Is it partly because the version with -O2 optimization option optimizing the instruction `bl      std::atomic<int*>::load(std::memory_order) const` by breaking it down in to more instructions?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
 
void print(int* val)
{
    std::cout << *val << std::endl;
}
 
int main()
{
    int x{42};
    std::atomic<int*> p = &x;
    int* local = p.load(std::memory_order_consume);
    print(local);
}
```

Comment: A strict count of the number of assembly instructions is not a good indicator of optimal code. One set of quick instructions might be able to replace a single slow instruction. Or it might be about using the pipeline in a more effective way, to avoid pipeline stalls.

Comment: it is to be expected that `-O2` has more optimizations than `-O0`. Whether this results in more or less assembly is up to the compiler. You seem to expect that more output is automatically worse. Why?

Comment: It looks like GCC simply inlines the second `<<` operator with `-O2` (for `std::endl`), so you get only less function call.

Comment: More instructions doesn't mean your code will run slower, and this is a result of how your processor instruction pipeline works.  One such factor : From the moment you start having branches (like loops) you will start to have branch predictions, failing branch predictions are very expensive because pipelines have to be reset resulting in slowing of your execution. So the compiler might actually unroll loops (create more instructions) to avoid this problem. Another approach is to avoid making calls through the callstack.

Comment: `bl      std::atomic<int*>::load(std::memory_order) const` is a function call. The compiler didn't inline it without optimizations, but did with. The body of that function contains many more instructions without optimizations enabled. Compiler explorer hides library symbols by default though. Click "Filter" and deselect "Library functions".

Comment: maybe you should try to benchmark the code with and without optimizations. If `-O2` results in faster execution all is fine, you learned something. If it turns out to be slower, then we have an issue to be discussed

Comment: If you want to know more about pipelining and why running more instructions might even be faster, watch this video from cppcon [branchless programming in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-WPhYREFjk)

Comment: Bottom line -- The number of assembly statements does not determine which code is faster or slower.  This has been the case since assembly language has been around -- doesn't matter if the processor is a Ryzen latest version or a Z80 from the 1970's.

Comment: If you really want the code to be _small_, that's what `-Os` is for.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Optimise Options provided with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). To quote: `-O2`: "Optimize even more. GCC performs nearly all supported optimizations that do not involve a space-speed tradeoff. As compared to -O, this option increases both compilation time and the performance of the generated code."

Comment: `-O2`  is compiling for *performance* not number of instructions or size of executable.  Compiling for performance is sometimes compatible with compiling for size (which typically means executable file size rather than number of instructions), but often not - depending on instruction set, etc there is a trade-off.  If you care about executable size (or, to some extent, number of instructions) and are willing to trade off performance to achieve that consider using `-Os` (optimise for size) or `-Oz` (even more aggressively optimise for size).

Comment: If you want to compare builds of the same source, it's usually easiest to put them side-by-side in the *same* Godbolt link, like https://godbolt.org/z/b3a1d4Gqb

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai : This specific code is too short to meaningfully benchmark.  It will spend almost all its time in startup overhead and making a `write` system call, and iostream machinery.

Comment: many optimizations like inlining, vectorization... increase code size significantly

Answer (score 4):

Compiler Explorer hides library function definitions by default. If you deselect 'Filter > Library functions', you will notice that the non-optimized version actually generates 143 lines of assembly, while the optimized version has only 52 lines of assembly. The library function definitions are optimized out in `-O2` due to function inlining.

Comment: It would be smaller still if `void print(int* val)` was declared `inline` or `static` so the compiler didn't have to make a stand-alone copy of the definition (which things outside that compilation unit could call).  Without that, GCC chooses not to inline it into `main` (which is implicitly `__attribute__((cold))` in GCC so optimization is biased toward size, not speed.  But for other functions it will inline: https://godbolt.org/z/aoGoh35hv).  It would also save size to use `<< '\n'` or `<< "\n"` instead of unnecessarily flushing the stream with `std::endl`.